# Difference between Trip and Route in Google Transit

Tags: google, route, transit

I am developing a transit webapp using Google Transit, while referring to documentation, i see two different datasets (trips.txt and routes.txt) but i can't clarify the difference between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Transit routes**. A route is a group of trips that are displayed to
>   riders as a single service. (The entire route)
>
> GTFS Routes are equivalent to "Lines" in public transportation
>   systems.  Routes are defined in the file routes.txt, and are made up
>   of one or more Trips - remember that a Trip occurs at a specific time
>   and so a Route is time independent.

trips (trips.txt) are individual components of routes (routes.txt)

example - there maybe many trips to 1 route

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference

http://support.google.com/transitpartners/answer/1106431?hl=en

Answer (score 7):

Here's the documentation from Google: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference

In this model, a "trip" occurs along a "route". I think the simplest difference can been seen in the fact that a "route" has no directionality, it's just a line along which a transit vehicle travels. So if you look only at the route, you don't know which direction along the line anything is travelling: you need a "trip" to know that.

I guess you could say that a "route" exists on the ground. And a "trip" is what happens when the transit vehicle travels on along the route.

(note I had to use the word "when" in that last sentence... which indicates that a "trip" extends a "route" with some time information)

Answer (score 0):

If you are travelling say from Point A to B, then 
a) Travelling from point A to B makes a TRIP. 
b) Travelling from point A to B and back to A again makes a ROUTE. The word ROUTE is normally used when you are travelling through intermediate stop points eg from point A through B, C, D, E etc and back to A again.

Comment: Please use references when possible to verify the content of your answer.

Comment: That's not what the GTFS documentation says. (See @Mapperz's answer)

Answer (score 0):

So, trying to come up with some concrete examples:

There's the '101' bus route; it goes between the Town Centre and the Airport, via the Bus Depot.

At 0450 every morning, the bus leaves the bus depot for the town centre. This is a trip, with only two stops.

Then it heads to the airport via the Bus Station at 0500; this is another trip. And then it returns to town; yet another trip. Each of these trips has three stops.

Some trips might take radically different paths to others -- perhaps a bus that serves a small village with a school takes a detour twice a day into the village to pickup/drop off at the school, bypassing the stops on the main route. That's OK -- those trips will just have different stops listed  in `stop_times.txt` to the more usual type of trip. But it's still called the 246, even when it does these detours -- that's what it means to be a route!

Whilst `routes.txt` describes the metadata for a route, conceptually a route is mostly an unordered collection of trips with a collective brand; and each those individual trips are mostly a sequence of stops with associated times in `stop_times.txt` (apart from the metadata in `trips.txt`).

[Hope that's right, I'm mostly writing this to solidify my own understanding]