# Can a trip exist without routes

Tags: google, route, transit

I have be finding a clear differences between trip and route terminologies. I am also developing a transit system using goole transit. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43928/difference-between-trip-and-route-in-google-transit) thread answers has a very clear explanation. But one confusion remains, can trip exist without routes? I think logically it can. But what about in google transit context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a trip cannot exist without an associated route in routes.txt.

The 'route_id' column for each trip in trips.txt is required and [must reference a route_id from routes.txt.](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#trips_fields)

Comment: Of course... I forgot to see the reference doc... Thank jmcbroom.